# Is it common to use the word "numb" to describe the after effect of being hit on the head?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage

Example:

> The bat hit me so hard it numbed me.

The reason I ask is because I only get [three](https://www.google.com.tw/search?biw=1280&bih=891&q=%22hit%20me%20so%20hard%20it%20numbed%22&oq=%22hit%20me%20so%20hard%20it%20numbed%22&gs_l=serp.3...2042.4615.0.5599.3.3.0.0.0.0.121.330.1j2.3.0.msedr...0...1c.1.64.serp..3.0.0.g1CjwEs1WIc) results on Google.

Is it common to use *numb* in a case like this (feeling dizzy after being hit with something)? Or is there a better alternative?

Comment: You're right, it's not the usual term. 'Dazed', 'stunned' or even 'stupefied' are more likely to be used.

Comment: What Erik said. I should add that becoming all over "numb" is more often the result of a _slower_ process, such as ingesting something you probably shouldn't, like a roofie. On the other hand, you could be hit on the elbow in such a way as to numb the arm. It is only the whole person who can be stunned, dazed and so forth.

Comment: No, because it's usually the opposite of being numb- it hurts like hell. You could refer to "seeing stars"- that false visual effect from being hit (or dropped) on your head.

Comment: You might say that it momentarily numbed your senses... delaying the "Ow!" for a full three seconds.

Comment: It's 6 results now actually:). Apparently the usage has seen a significant increase recently. I wonder how come:)

Comment: I suppose 'numbed all my inhibitions' or something like that would work, but the word 'numb' simply means to limit sensation as an anaesthetic would.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No it's not common as far as I'm aware of. Numb generally refers to the loss of feeling. Either physical or mental:

From [The free dictionary:](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/numb)

> 1. Deprived of the power to feel or move normally; benumbed: toes numb with cold; too numb with fear to cry out.
> 2. Emotionally unresponsive; indifferent: numb to yet another appeal.

I myself would use the word:

> [Dazed:](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/dazed) To stun or bewilder, as with a heavy blow or shock

Used like [here](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/daze).

Or as suggested by bib, and used in the above definition:

> [Stunned:](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/stunned) To daze or render senseless, as by a blow or loud noise.

Comment: Or as you imply, *stunned*.

Answer (score 1):

No it isn't common.

You got just 3 results because being hit on the head usually makes you feel a lot of pain, which isn't at all what `numb` the verb means.

[Oxford](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/numb) defines numb as:

> 1. Deprive of feeling or responsiveness:
> 2. Cause (a sensation) to be felt less intensely; deaden:

Something (like medication) can ***numb your pain*** after you're hit on the head. That is, it causes it to be felt less intensely.